# Invalid user input asks for input again without switch case/if-else/loops in main()

Tags: java, recursion

> This is for basic coding practice.Experience level is beginner.

*desired output*:

Enter 1-option A Enter 2-option B Enter 3-option C

*user i/p

*i/p specific implementation

*if any other i/p is received then*

Invalid option

Enter 1-option A, Enter 2-option B, Enter 3-option C

*user i/p

----------end of desired o/p------------

**Without using Switch case,Loops,If/else**

*my code*

```
import java.util.*;

public class Selection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to ABC Shopping Experience");
        System.out.println("Please make selection of items to purchase");
        System.out.println("Clothing-1");
        System.out.println("Electronics-2");
        System.out.println("Sport goods-3");

        new Scan();
        Scan.scan1();
        new Thankyou();
        Thankyou.display(); 
    }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scan {
    static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int first = scn.nextInt();
    static int count = 0;

    static Object scan1() {
        if(first == 1) 
            return new Clothing();
        else if (first == 2)
               return new Electronics();
        else if (first == 3)
            return new Sports();
        else {
               System.out.println("Invalid option ");   
            count++;
            
            if(count == 3) {
                Thankyou t1 = new Thankyou();
                Thankyou.display();
            } else {
                scan1();
            }
        }
        count=0;
        return new Thankyou();
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Thankyou {
    static void display() {
        System.out.println("thank you come again");
     }
}
```

-------Output-----

```
Welcome to ABC Shopping Experience
Please make selection of items to purchase
Clothing-1
Electronics-2
Sport goods-3
6
Invalid option 
Invalid option 
Invalid option 
thank you come again
thank you come again
```

-----END OF OPUTPUT-----

All classes in same package.

I understand it is easier with switch/loop but this is the process i want to learn.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you using classes (Thankyou and Scan) and not two methods?

Comment: @0ddlyokoi wish to add more classes to the Scan class which may be used in other classes.
I accept Thankyou class is redundant but by creating object of the Thankyou class i can display the thank you message when desired instead of a println("Thank you") .

Comment: @Saby You can achieve the same thing using methods instead of classes